# Pandas to mark both if cell value is a substring of another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

A column with short and full form of people names, I want to unify them, if the name is a part of the other name. e.g. "James.J" and "James.Jones", I want to tag them both as "James.J".

```
data = {'Name': ["Amelia.Smith",
"Lucas.M",
"James.J",
"Elijah.Brown",
"Amelia.S",
"James.Jones",
"Benjamin.Johnson"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I can't figure out how to do it in Pandas. So only a xlrd way, with similarity ratio by SequenceMatcher (and sort it manually in Excel):

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy 

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\TEM\\input.xlsx")

old_sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

wb = copy(workbook) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 

for row_index in range(0, old_sheet.nrows):

    current = old_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    previous = old_sheet.cell(row_index-1, 0).value
    sro = SequenceMatcher(None, current.lower(), previous.lower(), autojunk=True).ratio()

    if sro > 0.7:
        sheet.write(row_index, 1, previous)
        sheet.write(row_index-1, 1, previous)

wb.save("C:\\TEM\\output.xls")
```

What's the nice Pandas way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using `apply` with a custom function.  For small dfs this should be fine; this will not scale well for large dfs.  A more sophisticated data structure for `memo` would be an ok place to start to improve performance without degrading readability too much:

```
df = df.sort_values("Name")
def short_name(row, col="Name", memo=[]):
    name = row[col]
    for m_name in memo:
        if name.startswith(m_name):
            return m_name
    memo.append(name)
    return name

df["short_name"] = df.apply(short_name, axis=1)        
df = df.sort_index()
```

output:

```
               Name        short_name
0      Amelia.Smith          Amelia.S
1           Lucas.M           Lucas.M
2           James.J           James.J
3      Elijah.Brown      Elijah.Brown
4          Amelia.S          Amelia.S
5       James.Jones           James.J
6  Benjamin.Johnson  Benjamin.Johnson
```

Comment: thank you. is it possible to put it side by side with the original data?

Comment: sure, gimme a sec

Comment: @MarkK I have updated the solution to be a bit cleaner, fyi

Answer (score 2):

using pandas, making use of `str.split` and `.map` with some boolean conditions to identify the dupes.

```
df1 = df['Name'].str.split('.',expand=True).rename(columns={0 : 'FName',  1 :'LName'})

df2 = df1.loc[df1['FName'].duplicated(keep=False)]\
     .assign(ky=df['Name'].str.len())\
     .sort_values('ky')\
     .drop_duplicates(subset=['FName'],keep='first').drop('ky',1)
```

---

```
df['NewName'] = df1['FName'].map(df2.assign(newName=df2.agg('.'.join,1))\
                             .set_index('FName')['newName'])



print(df)

               Name   NewName
0      Amelia.Smith  Amelia.S
1           Lucas.M       NaN
2           James.J   James.J
3      Elijah.Brown       NaN
4          Amelia.S  Amelia.S
5       James.Jones   James.J
6  Benjamin.Johnson       NaN
```